# Mac: Uninstall MonoDevelop Add-In: Mono for Android

Tags: macos, add-in, monodevelop, xamarin.android

Sorry if Stack Overflow is not the right place for this question.

I have previously developed an iOS application using MonoDevelop and the MonoTouch stack on Mac OS X Snow Leopard. Now this app had to be ported to Android.

For that reason, I have been experimenting with the evaluation version of Mono for Android to allow code re-usage (where possible) and to compare it to the more native Android stack (Eclipse/ADT). I've decided to go with Eclipse/ADT for Android and stick with MonoDevelop/MonoTouch only for iOS.

However, Mono for Android doesn't seem to be happy with that. I've not found a way to get rid of it. How can I uninstall the Mono for Android framework and (more importantly) the MonoDevelop Add-In? I don't see a reason for regularly installing updates for it or even (possibly) letting it interfere with my MonoTouch developement stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting this folder did the trick:

```
/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do something similar on my Mac, except that I ended up completely uninstalling Mono, including MonoTouch. After using AppCleaner to remove MonoDevelop, I ran the following command from the terminal:

```
sudo find / -name 'mono'
```

I found that I also had to remove /Developer/MonoAndroid and /Developer/MonoTouch. In your case, removing the former should be all you have to do.